# integral, domain bounded by planes

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have to determine the volume of the domain which is bounded by the plane $x=0, y=0, z=-2, z=4-x-y$. I have an integral$$\iiint 1 \,dx\,dy\,dz$$ but I don't know the limits. Could you explain me how to find out the limits of the integral? If I integrate first to z the limits are -2 and z=4-x-y of z but I dont know how to continue

Comment: Did you try drawing a sketch?

Comment: equation of plane $x+y+z=4$ change it to intercept form then try figure out

Comment: Yes but I i dont know how the domain looks correctly

Comment: You mean x/4+y/4+z/4=1? The intersection of the plane with the x achsis is (4,0,0), with the y-achsis (0,4,0) and with the z-achsis (0,0,4) but I dont know how to continue

Answer (score 0):

Since your requirements give a limit on $z$ that depends on $x$ and $y$, you are correct that you should integrate $z$ first from $-2$ to $4-x-y$. We now need bounds on $x$ and $y$.

Your requirements are four planes, which in 3-space bound a tetrahedron, which is defined by its four vertices. We can find each vertex by solving a set of three out of the four given requirements.

Leaving out the first equation, we have $y=0$, $z=-2$, and

$$z=4-x-y$$
$$-2=4-x-0$$
$$x=6$$

So our first vertex is $(6,0,-2)$.

Leaving out the second equation, we have $x=0$, $z=-2$, and

$$z=4-x-y$$
$$-2=4-0-y$$
$$y=6$$

So our second vertex is $(0,6,-2)$.

Leaving out the third equation, we have $x=0$, $y=0$, and

$$z=4-x-y$$
$$z=4-0-0$$
$$z=4$$

So our third vertex is $(0,0,4)$.

Leaving out the fourth equation, we have $x=0$, $y=0$, $z=-2$. So our third vertex is $(0,0,-2)$.

We see that last two vertices have the same $x$ and $y$ coordinates. Since we want limits on $x$ and $y$, if we leave out the $z$'s we see that we have a triangle with the vertices $(6,0),\ (0,6),\ (0,0)$. This is easy to sketch and we can easily derive limits on $x$ and $y$. Let's arbitrarily choose to have $y$ depend on $x$, so we have $x$ going from $0$ to $6$ and so $y$ goes from $0$ to $6-x$ (can you see that from the sketch?). The desired integral is then

> $$\int_{x=0}^6 \int_{y=o}^{6-x} \int_{z=-2}^{4-x-y} 1\,dz\,dy\,dx$$